# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: node.js, flutter

i am trying to fetch the data from api, i am getting the value when i print it in console, but when i am tried to access it using shared perference on other screen, i am not getting the values, and it print this error

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

here is my api code

```
getstatus=(req,res)=>{
  jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'secret' , function(err, decoded) {
    if(err) {
     err["expiredAt"] = err["expiredAt"].toLocaleString();  //here the error points
     res.status(300).json(err)
    }
    else
      {
  let leaves=0,sick_leaves=0,annual_leaves=0,maternity_leaves=0;
  
  User.find({"username":req.body.username,"leave":"ON"},function(err,data){
      User.find({"username":req.body.username,"leave":"ON","type":"Sick"},function(err,value){
        
          User.find({"username":req.body.username,"leave":"ON","type":"annual"},function(err,value1){
      
              User.find({"username":req.body.username,"leave":"ON","type":"maternity"},function(err,value2){
                console.log(value2.length)
                if(data.length>0){
                    leaves = data.length
                  }    
                if(value2.length>0){
                     maternity_leaves= value2.length
                  }    
                  if(value.length>0){
                     sick_leaves= value.length}
                    if(value1.length>0){
                        annual_leaves= value1.length
                      }             
         console.log(leaves,sick_leaves,annual_leaves,maternity_leaves)             
         res.json({"leaves":leaves,"sick":sick_leaves,"annual":annual_leaves,"maternity":maternity_leaves}).status(200)
                      
              })    
  
          })
          
      })
      
  })
}})
  
}
```

and here i am fetching the api on frontend

```
 data={ 
          "token":token,
          "username":name,
          "leave":"ON",
          "type":"maternity"
        };
         dio
          .post(localHostUrlleaveCount, data: json.encode(data))
            .then((onResponse) async {
              print(onResponse.data);

              String sickCount=(onResponse.data['sick'].toString());
              print("sickCount");  //i get value here 
              print(sickCount);
              String annualCount=(onResponse.data['annual'].toString());
              String maternityCount=(onResponse.data['maternity']);
              String totalleaveCount=(onResponse.data['leaves']);
              print("annualcount");
              print(annualCount); // but it prints this "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'"
 error before this line 
              
              myPrefs.setString('totalleave', totalleaveCount);
              myPrefs.setString('sickcount', sickCount);
              myPrefs.setString('annualcount', annualCount);
              myPrefs.setString('maternitycount', maternityCount);

            }).catchError((onerror){
              print(onerror.toString());
            // showAlertDialog(context);
          });
```

and on dashboard screen i getting the shared perference value like this

```
String sickcount="";
 _userDetails() async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      sickcount=myPrefs.getString('sickcount');
      print(int.parse(sickcount));  //error on this way "Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)"
      print(sickcount);  //i tried in this way
      print(sickcount.toString());  //i tried in this way but same error on all the ways
      
     
    });
  }
```

i am getting values perfectly from other api's, i don't know what i am doing wrong with this api, please help me to fix it.

**one more thing** i am doing is when i am logged in in app i am calling the dashboard screen on click on login button, but i want this above api output in leave screen, so when i create this api on leave screen and call it in initState function it send me this error on backend

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined
```

and `Http status error [500]`  error on frontend

**Api output is**

```
 {leaves: 3, sick: 2, annual: 0, maternity: 1}
```

Comment: can you show us the output of print(onResponse.data)?

Comment: @TryHarder i edit my post with api output, please check

Comment: print("sickCount");  //i get value here  , what value did you get here?

Comment: 2, but i resolved it, it was my mistake, i was calling the dashboad screen first then calling the api, so that's why i was not getting the value.

Comment: Good to hear that man, keep it up!